# Tensorflow (tfjs) - Saving a trained model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm using tfjs (tensorflow.js) and I trained a model with some data.

My question:

How can I save the model I just trained and use it later in my app?

Comment: Follow this link https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/save_load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 0.11 tensorflow.js now has a tf.model.save() method currently being described under the loadModel section in the documentation. 
[Found here](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.11.2/#loadModel)

Answer (score 1):

Its'not available now but this featture is [planned](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/13) as they tell at [f.a.q.](https://js.tensorflow.org/faq/)